# How to design overlapping buttons one over the other?

Tags: html, css, responsive, google-web-designer

[image has the design][1]Image describes the design I want. What i have tried is, i have kept three buttons together and tried putting z-index , position absolute , relative,
but didnt worked.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OxFO.png

The code i have tried is, i have applied three buttons together   :
 123

and what i am getting is looks something like this   [This is the image what i made]
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruxL5.png

Comment: Also post your tried code

Comment: please post your code along with your question

Comment: You have to just apply top and bottom padding for middle button and float:left to each one

Comment: Apologies, i am new to asking questions over here. I have posted my code and image also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this example. Home you got what you want.
 http://embed.plnkr.co/ExU03A42KNqr6XakFo4I/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  <style>
    button{
      width:120px;
      height:40px;
      margin:-5px;
      background:#ee5353;
      border:1px solid gray;
      border-radius:3px;
    }
    button:nth-child(2){
      height:60px;
      position:relative;z-index:2;
    }
  </style>
</head>
  <body>
   <button>1</button>
   <button>2</button>
   <button>3</button>

  </body>

</html>
```